# Unexpected results with parallel numba jit

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba, jit

I'm trying to parallelize [this](https://github.com/ec-jrc/nrt/blob/4a7c078fda02b3480ca0d967dd17dbcfaec4330f/nrt/stats.py#L21) numba jitted function. I initially thought this would be trivial since it is an embarrassingly parallel problem, but it produces unexpected results (different output for the sequential and parallel 'implementations'). Any idea what could be happening there and whether there are ways to make this work?

See reproducible example below:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def nanlstsq(X, y):
    """Return the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation

    Analog to ``numpy.linalg.lstsq`` for dependant variable containing ``Nan``

    Args:
        X ((M, N) np.ndarray): Matrix of independant variables
        y ({(M,), (M, K)} np.ndarray): Matrix of dependant variables

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: Least-squares solution, ignoring ``Nan``
    """
    beta = np.zeros((X.shape[1], y.shape[1]), dtype=np.float64)
    for idx in range(y.shape[1]):
        # subset y and X
        isna = np.isnan(y[:,idx])
        X_sub = X[~isna]
        y_sub = y[~isna,idx]
        # Compute beta on data subset
        XTX = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X_sub.T, X_sub))
        XTY = np.dot(X_sub.T, y_sub)
        beta[:,idx] = np.dot(XTX, XTY)
    return beta


@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def nanlstsq_parallel(X, y):
    beta = np.zeros((X.shape[1], y.shape[1]), dtype=np.float64)
    for idx in numba.prange(y.shape[1]):
        # subset y and X
        isna = np.isnan(y[:,idx])
        X_sub = X[~isna]
        y_sub = y[~isna,idx]
        # Compute beta on data subset
        XTX = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X_sub.T, X_sub))
        XTY = np.dot(X_sub.T, y_sub)
        beta[:,idx] = np.dot(XTX, XTY)
    return beta




# Generate random data
n_targets = 10000
n_features = 3
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=n_features,
                       n_targets=n_targets)
# Add random nan to y array
y.ravel()[np.random.choice(y.size, 5*n_targets, replace=False)] = np.nan
# Run the regression
beta = nanlstsq(X, y)
beta_parallel = nanlstsq_parallel(X, y)


np.testing.assert_allclose(beta, beta_parallel)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is causing the difference between the sequential and parallel versions, but computing the inverse of `X_sub.T @ X_sub` is not recommended for solving matrix equations - [don't invert that matrix](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix). If you still want to compute the normal equations then you should use [numpy.linalg.solve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy-linalg-solve) or without computing the normal equations, you can use [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy-linalg-lstsq) both of which are compatible with numba and pass your `assert_allclose` test with the sequential version:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def nanlstsq_parallel_solve(X, y):
    beta = np.zeros((X.shape[1], y.shape[1]), dtype=np.float64)
    for idx in numba.prange(y.shape[1]):
        # subset y and X
        isna = np.isnan(y[:,idx])
        X_sub = X[~isna]
        y_sub = y[~isna,idx]
        beta[:, idx] = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X_sub.T, X_sub), np.dot(X_sub.T, y_sub))
    return beta


@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def nanlstsq_parallel_lstsq(X, y):
    beta = np.zeros((X.shape[1], y.shape[1]), dtype=np.float64)
    for idx in numba.prange(y.shape[1]):
        # subset y and X
        isna = np.isnan(y[:,idx])
        X_sub = X[~isna]
        y_sub = y[~isna,idx]
        beta[:, idx] = np.linalg.lstsq(X_sub, y_sub)[0]
    return beta


beta_parallel_solve = nanlstsq_parallel_solve(X, y)
beta_parallel_lstsq = nanlstsq_parallel_lstsq(X, y)


np.testing.assert_allclose(beta, beta_parallel_solve)
np.testing.assert_allclose(beta, beta_parallel_lstsq)
```

Comment: Good point. Note that using `numba.prange` is certainly not a good idea here. At least not without using a specific BLAS configuration (like the sequential one). Indeed, `X_sub.T @ X_sub` should be already performed in parallel. Some BLAS/Lapack might even parallelise `np.linalg.solve`. Running parallel code from multiple thread results in an over-subscription that can drastically reduce performance on many systems (especially HPC ones). Besides, `beta` can be transposed at the end more efficiently than writing columns. Also please note that `~isna` is computed twice.

Comment: Thanks @JérômeRichard and Nin17, I'm truely impressed by the quality of your insights. We didn't get to the *why* of my initial attempt failing, but the answers provided are very helpful. Also I played a bit the openblas config and limiting to a single thread improves performances of the sequential approach too, which somewhat makes sense given that the loop makes it a lot of very small tasks.